# ST_Within between 2 Multilinestrings not matching in PostGIS/QGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm working with QGIS 3.4 LTR.
I have 2 geometric tables with Multilinestring type geometry in the same SRID : Table1 (thin black lines with thin black labels) and Table2 (thick colored lines with buffer zone labels).

I want to get the id of Table2 features in Table1 column named id_table1
 when : geometries of Table1 are within geometries of Table2 OR geometries of Table1 contain geometries of Table2 OR when the geometries of the 2 tables features overlaps.

[image: Map canva extract]

I have this query :

```
SELECT table1.id AS "id_table1",
string_agg(table2.id::text,',') AS "id_table2"
FROM schema.table1
LEFT JOIN schema.table2 ON ST_WITHIN (table1.geom,table2.geom) OR ST_CONTAINS (table1.geom,table2.geom) OR ST_OVERLAPS (table1.geom,table2.geom)
GROUP BY table1.id
```

In the table extract, we can see that id_table1 80, 83 and 87 did not get id_table2 :

[image: Table extract]

Comment: The function works for lines, it can be verified with `select ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0,0 4)'),ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0, 0 10)'));` which returns "true".

Comment: what exactly does "*not working*" mean...that you don't get any matches? if `ST_Contains(A, B)` "*is working*", `ST_Within(B, A)` should, too.

Comment: @Taras, I added a image

Comment: II added more details to understanding

Comment: @ThingumaBob, yes I don't get any matches

Comment: @user30184 I tested your query and it returns "false"

Comment: postgis documentation of st_overlaps says: *Returns TRUE if the Geometries "spatially overlap". By that we mean they intersect, but one does not completely contain another.*  Maybe st_intersects(a, b) gives better results, combined with 'and not st_touches(a, b)'

Comment: Very, very odd that my PostGIS returns true and your PostGIS returns false with the same query. My version is 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1. I suppose that use run it exactly as it is without any modifications.

Comment: @user30184 : sorry, your query with your coordinates returns true. It returns false with the coordinates of  id_table2 = 3876 and id_table1 = 87.

Comment: Well, my guess is that ST_Within is not true for those. Without your geometries to test with it is impossible to say more. Topological comparisons with points and lines tend to be very sensitive because of inaccuracies in floating point computing. Coordinates may be the same till 12th decimal until they differ but the result is still "false".

Comment: you could try to `ST_SnapToGrid` both geometries in the comparison with a tiny grid. you can try and debug by joining `... ON ST_Dimension(ST_Intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom)) = <dim>`, with `<dim>` being either 0 (Point) or 1 (Linestring); see if those ids missing in your table above show up when the intersection is a point. also, this covers all your conditions (faster would be `ST_Relate` directly). btw. did you mean `ST_Contains` returns correct results?